# Combinations of towers

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

You have 25 red blocks and 25 blue blocks.
You can stack the blocks in any order into 5 towers with 5 blocks maximum in each tower.
You do not have to use all the blocks and blocks cannot float in mid-air.
How many combinations of towers can you make?
The base being 0 0 0 0 0 as 1 of the combinations.
So you could have in stack 1: ABBBA 2:0 3: BBA 4: BABAB 5:AAAAA.
How do you calculate how many options there are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are 25 blocks of each color, there is no limitation on the use of block, which means there won't the case where you don't have enough block of either color.

Then, since each tower are independent from each other, the total amount options is just how many options you have for each tower and raise it to the power of 5. i.e.$\text{Total Options}=(\text{options of each tower})^5$

For each tower, you can have 0 block, 1 block, 2, 3, 4, or 5 blocks. Therefore, the options you have for each tower is $2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5=2^6-1=63$

So, $\text{Total Options}=63^5=992436543$

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Each tower is independient to each other. 
This is due to $25 \geq 5 \cdot 5$ and you don't have to worry if the blocks run out.

So, in each tower: i blocks $\implies$ $2^i$ posibilities, i from 0 to 5.

Answer: $(1 + 2 +... + 32)^5 = 63^5$.